# shell_exec freezing on calling ConvertHTMLtoImage

Tags: php, capture, shell-exec

I have a bot running taking preview captures of sites linked on my site. I use a program called [converthtmltoimage](http://www.converthtmltoimage.com) for that. The program grabbing the thumbs is running on a windows server. I use the command line option through a shell_exec. However... converthtmltoimage has the tendency to freeze on certain websites. Resulting in the command not being executed and freezing my PHP code as well.

What can I do to resolve this? Either enabling some sort of timeout on the shell_exec or an alternative to converthtmltoimage I would assume...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
  $oExec = $WshShell->Run("<add program and parameters here>", 7, false);
```

Mind you, only works on Windows!

Comment: Actually that is PHP on Windows, on Linux it won't work :) (obviously). Just check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php